# Saving asynchronously downloaded files' contents to SQLITE

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asynchronous

**BACKGROUND**  I am looping through a bunch of URLs to get several files downloaded.  When the files are downloaded I need to 'unpack' the JSON from the files and insert the data into an SQLite database.

**PROBLEM**  When the file is downloaded I attempt to insert the contents of the file into the database and because the files are downloaded asynchronously and the files are different sizes the second file tried to get inserted into the database before the first file has finished and so the database is locked for the subsequent files.

**QUESTION**  How do I get the files to wait for the previous one to be saved to the database before attempting to save the next?

Code to get the files:

```
-(void)downloadJsonDataFrom:(NSURL *)url withToken:(NSString*)token saveTo:(NSString *)saveLocation withName:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:(@"content-type")];
    [request addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:(@"X-TOKEN")]; 

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {

    if (!error && data) {

        NSError *writeError = nil;
        BOOL writeOK = [data writeToFile:saveLocation options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];

        if (writeOK) {
            NSLog(@"downloadTheFileFrom writeOK for %@", fileName);
           [sqlFileHandler saveJsonToSql:saveLocation];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error writing file : %@ %@", fileName, writeError);
        }


    } else {
        NSLog(@"downloadTheFileFrom Error : %@",error);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: Write all files to disk first and then to database

Comment: @schmidt9 When I move the 'save to database' code out, it gets run BEFORE the files has finished downloaded, as the files take a few seconds to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a serial queue from GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). Some untested code:

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.sql.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        [sqlFileHandler saveJsonToSql:saveLocation];
    });
```

and something a little swifty-er for those of that persuasion:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.unique.sql.queue", attr: DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
serialQueue.sync { 
    operationThatNeedsToRunSerially()
}
```

Comment: I have wrapped the saveJsonToSql method call in the DispatchQueue and the database still gets locked, although not always.

Comment: Try dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async.